# how to change the name of the variables in the stargazer regression table?

Tags: r, regression, stargazer

my regression model:

```
ModelBIC<-lm(parent ~ log(totinc) + male + as.factor(race) + year + as.factor(educ) + age + state)
```

my table:

```
stargazer(ModelBIC,type="html",title="Final Model",out = "Final Model.htm")
```

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgnXr.png)

the problem is how can I change those factor name?

I tried convert those to factor before the model, it just wont work.
I want to turn as.factor(educ)1 to elementary; 2 to high school; 3 to college.
any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by adding `covariate.lables=c()`, see below.
Further information can be found [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/vignettes/stargazer.pdf)

As you did not deliver any data I used `data(mtcars)`.

```
model <- lm(mpg~ cyl + vs + am + gear, data = mtcars)
stargazer(model, type = 'html', header = FALSE,
          covariate.labels=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))
```

[image]

---

Update for your comment: *and what if I dont want to show b or c in the table?*

If you mean just level the 2 labels out, you can use empty strings for those, like so `covariate.labels = c("a", "", "", "d")` . As this does not make much sense I guess you mean not reporting the two covariates at all.
This can be done by adding `keep = ...`  .

```
model <- lm(mpg~ cyl + vs + am + gear, data = mtcars )
stargazer(model, type = 'html', header = FALSE,
          #covariate.labels=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),
          keep = c("cyl", 'am'))
```

[image]

Comment: and what if I dont want to show b or c in the table?

Comment: @`Ma Feihai`  see my answer to your comment in the new edit.